# How to assign single variable to multiple objects in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: object, variables, adobe-illustrator

I couldn't find a solution on how to assign a single variable data to mulple objects in illustrator.

I have two text objects in illustrator document. I need to show same text in both objects. If I assign single variable to the second object will unassign that variable with the first one.

**Is there any solution for using a single variable with multiple objects in Adobe *Illustrator*?**

Comment: Probably there is an misunderstanding of the concept of variables. To make several text objects to change simultaneously you need to select them, to select a variable and click on 'Make Text Dynamic'. After that content of all selected text objects will change accordingly when you change your 'Data Sets'. But in the palette you will see several variables with the same name -- they are the one variable actually.

Answer (score 1):

Look, here your data set (CSV-file):

```
var1,var2,var3
a1,b1,c1
a2,b2,c2
a3,b3,c3
```

Here are your text objects:

[image]

Click 'Import', select your csv file with data set and get the variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3` in the palette:

[image]

Select your text objects, select a variable, say variable `var2` and click 'Make Text Dynamic':

[image]

Now you have 3 variables `var2`

[image]

Select Data Set 1:

[image]

And content all of the three text objects will change with value ('b1') from var2 in your csv file:

[image]

If you will change data set to 'Data Set 2', you will get 'b2', etc.

[image]

Comment: When I try this, I get the message 'A filter cannot be complete because of an unknown error.' see video... https://youtu.be/1TX4TrC8glI ...do you know why this happening? Thanks

Comment: No. Alas, I don't know what could cause this error.